# JavaScript function that grabs element not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm trying to make a function that grabs a HTML element and then after I've selected the HTML element I try to apply CSS to it via JavaScript but it doesn't seem to work. Instead, I get an error that says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined". What am I doing wrong?

```
document.querySelector('h1').style.color = 'brown';
```

(this works though)

Wardrobe.js:

```
function qSelector(element) {
    document.querySelector(element);
}

qSelector('h1').style.color = 'brown';
```

index.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 id="thing">Header 1</h1>
        <script src="Wardrobe.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I expect the color of `<h1>` to be brown but it's still black.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not returning the element from the function `qSelector` (which by default returns `undefined`, hence `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of`**`undefined`**):

```js
function qSelector(element) {
  return document.querySelector(element);   // <-- return the element
}

qSelector('h1').style.color = 'brown';
```

```html
<h1 id="thing">Header 1</h1>
```